# I have RecyclerCards. When you click on the card, a new activity should open

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, mobile

RecyclerAdapter.

Here I registered Adapter for RecyclerView with CardView. The main problem is that he started doing mobile development quite recently and there is simply not enough knowledge.

```java
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private  static final String TAG ="RecyclerView";
    private  Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Game> gamesList;


    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Game> gamesList){
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.gamesList=gamesList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_games_items, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(gamesList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.textView1.setText(gamesList.get(position).getTag());
    holder.textView2.setText(gamesList.get(position).getPrice());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(gamesList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return gamesList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView, textView1, textView2;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_img_id);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_title_id);
            textView1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_tags_id);
            textView2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_price_id);
            

        }
    }
}
```

Games.

There should be a click and transition to a new activity containing games description. Information is taken from FireBase database.

```java
public class Games extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    private ArrayList<Game> gamesList;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_games);
        ImageButton Home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
        Home.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton Lupa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lupa);
        Lupa.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton Calendar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        Calendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton Kubik = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.kubik);
        Kubik.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton Profile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);
        Profile.setOnClickListener(this);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        gamesList= new ArrayList<>();


        GetDataFromFirebase();

    }

    private void GetDataFromFirebase(){

        Query query_adventures = myRef.child("Parsing/Adventures");
        Query query_indi= myRef.child("Parsing/Indi");
        Query query_casuals= myRef.child("Parsing/Casuals");
        Query query_freegames= myRef.child("Parsing/Freegames");
        Query query_mmos= myRef.child("Parsing/Mmos");
        Query query_races= myRef.child("Parsing/Races");
        Query query_RP = myRef.child("Parsing/RP");
        Query query_simulator = myRef.child("Parsing/Simulator");

        query_adventures.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        query_indi.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        query_casuals.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        query_freegames.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        query_mmos.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        query_races.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        query_RP.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        query_simulator.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game games = new Game();

                    games.setImage(snapshot.child("IMG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTitle(snapshot.child("TITLE").getValue().toString());
                    games.setTag(snapshot.child("TAG").getValue().toString());
                    games.setPrice(snapshot.child("PRICE").getValue().toString());
                    gamesList.add(games);
                }

                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), gamesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void ClearAll(){
        if(gamesList!=null){
            gamesList.clear();

            if(recyclerAdapter!=null)
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        gamesList= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView, textView1, textView2;
        CardView cardView;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_img_id);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_title_id);
            textView1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_tags_id);
            textView2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_price_id);
        }

        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, News.class));
                break;
            case R.id.lupa:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Games.class));
                break;
            case R.id.calendar:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Calendar.class));
                break;
            case R.id.kubik:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Random_game.class));
                break;
            case R.id.profile:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Profile.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a beginners Android tutorial, it will be a lot more useful than a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to another activity using ViewHolder

```
public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

       itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
             //  perform your action here 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Pass your data using Intent putExtra() and can get your data in Game Class using getExtraString().